# Which version of JDK do I need to write Minecraft mods for the current version of Minecraft and Forge?

Tags: java, minecraft, minecraft-forge

The current Minecraft version (and the one any of my mods would target) is 1.17.1. Forge recently released a version that matches this (you need Forge 1.17.1 for MC 1.17.1, etc).

Oracle says that the latest JDK is 17 (like, I've only been away from Java for like 3 years... how the hell are they chewing through version numbers like this, ugh).

I've managed to dig through some forum posts that suggest that JDK 16 didn't work with earlier Forge versions, and I think that it holds true for later Forge versions (reflection was unavailable) and almost certainly for later JDK versions. But whether I could do work with JDK 15 or would need a still lower version, I'm having trouble figuring out. I was hoping someone could spare me the next 2 weeks of forum posts and half-assed experiments.

So in summary, what is the maximum JDK version that will give me minimum trouble? (I've got a minimum version from the IDE/extensions itself, and they don't seem especially generous).

Comment: Java 8.  *"Starting from Minecraft 1.12, Java 8 will be required to run Minecraft. If you don't know whether you have Java 8, don't worry - our installers supply Minecraft with its own version of Java by default."* - Source: https://www.minecraft.net/en-us/get-minecraft

Answer (score 5):

> Which version of JDK do I need to write Minecraft mods for the current version of Minecraft and Forge?

It depends on your Minecraft version.

> *"Starting from Minecraft 1.12, Java 8 will be required to run Minecraft. If you don't know whether you have Java 8, don't worry - our installers supply Minecraft with its own version of Java by default."*

Source: https://minecraft.net/en-us/get-minecraft

> *"Starting from Java Edition 1.17, Java 16 is required to run Java Edition. If the player does not know whether they have Java 16, the Minecraft launcher supplies Java Edition with its own version of Java by default."*
>
> *"Starting from Java Edition 1.18, Java 17 is required to run Java Edition. If the player does not know whether they have Java 17, the Minecraft Launcher supplies Java Edition with its own version of Java by default."*

Source: https://minecraft.fandom.com/wiki/Java_Edition#Software

Notes:

1. The above information is a direct quote from sources that *should be* reliable.  However, the quotes (and the sources) are liable to become out of date, so check the links for updates!
2. While you can (technically) develop on a later version of Java than the Minecraft platform uses, you will need to *build* with that version or older as the **target** Java version.  A JVM will not run bytecodes with a more recent classfile version number.  You will get a classloader error.
3. Beware of using preview features in your mods.  If you use them, then the platform has to be run with preview features enabled, or you will get classloader errors.

---

> Oracle says that the latest JDK is 17.

The OpenJDK team have moved to a *release cadence* of a new release every 6 months.  Certain releases are designated LTS releases (8, 11, 17).  Other releases go *end of life* immediately on the release of following one.  Thus Java 16 is end of life ... and Java 21 (LTS) is due out later this year (2023).

> ... how the hell are they chewing through version numbers like this, ugh.

They can't please everyone :-)